# Hero banner text alignment issue with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

[image]

I have a similar design like the one attached here and having to build this using Bootstrap 4.x. I'm struggling with the hero banner as it spans across the full width of the page and the blue box has text that aligns with the logo. I've used 'container' class to wrap the logo and links. Since the blue box starts from the left of the window and spans across almost half the width of the window I'm unable to use the same container class. **My question is how do I align the text in the blue box with the logo as shown in the attached picture please?**
Any suggestions/help much appreciated.

```css
.logo{ font-size: 50px;}
ul{ display: flex; margin-bottom: 0;}
li{ list-style: none; margin-right: 20px}
.hero-left{background-color: #158df2;}
h1{color: white;}
.hero-right{ height: 600px; width: 60%; background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1608754786700-002ea0379062?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2769&q=80')}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="container d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <div class="logo">
      Logo
    </div>   
    <nav>
      <ul class="d-flex">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="hero d-flex">
    <div class="hero-left">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Some text goes here lorem ipsum dolor...</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hero-right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
  

h1{
font-size:35px ! important;}

    .text{
    margin-left:45px;
   margin-right:40px;}
.logo{ font-size: 50px;}
ul{ display: flex; margin-bottom: 0;}
li{ list-style: none; margin-right: 20px}
.hero-left{background-color: #158df2;}
h1{color: white;}
.hero-right{ height: 600px; width: 60%; background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1608754786700-002ea0379062?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2769&q=80')}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="container d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <div class="logo">
      logo
    </div>   
    <nav>
      <ul class="d-flex">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="hero d-flex">
    <div class="hero-left">
      <div class="container">
<div class="text">

        <h1>Some text goes here lorem ipsum dolor...</h1>
</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hero-right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I just created a new div inside and set its margin to align with your logo. Your Font size in snippet is too large and what you tried to achieve in that it is small there is !important in font size its kind of not good make sure your style sheet is after bootstrap and bootstrap will not overwrite your styles

Comment: Thanks Divyang for taking the time to answer but this is not what I'm after as the fixed margin left and right doesn't work when you resize the window.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below code as per your required styling of header and banners.

```css
.logo {
  font-size: 50px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 20px
}

.hero-left {
  width: 50vw;
  background-color: #158df2;
  height: 600px;
}

h1 {
  color: black;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.hero-right {
  height: 600px;
  width: 50vw;
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1608754786700-002ea0379062?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2769&q=80')
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="container d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <div class="logo">
      Logo
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul class="d-flex">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="d-flex" style="position: relative">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Some text goes here lorem ipsum dolor...</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex" style="position: absolute; z-index: -1">
      <div class="hero-left">
      </div>
      <div class="hero-right"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Abhishek. My first attempt was something along the lines of your answer. However, I want the text block to be flexible enough to accommodate the text, therefore I cannot give it a fixed height unfortunately. I want the text to be inside the blue box so I know that the box will expand/shrink freely as the content changes.

Comment: Hey @Zac, I haven't given text fixed height so it should adjust to the screen size as you want. I have just defined the max-width so that it stays in the first column as per your requirement. If you think this is breaking at any point let me know about it I will provide a solution to that. But for your current scenario i guess this is styling to use

Comment: Sorry I meant the blue box. Since the blue box is just sitting behind the text rather than wrapping the text it will not adjust based on the content, if that makes sense? I appreciate this is a bit of tricky one to implement. What happens when you place the blue box outside of the text content is that it'll not change its size based on how text grows/shrink. As per the design, the blue box has a top and bottom padding and the text will determine the height of the blue box. Thanks again for your time - much appreciated,